How to alter column data type from varchar to double precision?
I am unable to change data type for population in Postgres. This is the error I got:

ERROR:  column "population" cannot be cast automatically to type double precision
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING population::double precision".

I have tried all data type options. I changed from varchar to float, numeric, int, bigint.

Do as the error message tells you:
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN population TYPE float8 USING population::float8;

float8 being a shorter alias of double precision.
Related:

Rails Migrations: tried to change the type of column from string to integer


it worked thanks
